# Datatime picker for Bootstrap 4 won't pop-up

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datetime, bootstrap-4

I'm experiencing problem to integrate EONASDAN datetime picker form into my Bootstrap v4 page.

I have a bunch of datas to be sent by a GET form.

In the test page below, i would like the user pick choices in each text box and select a datetime.

http://s529471052.onlinehome.fr/datetimeform/gpio/test.htm

However the datetime form won't pop-up.

For my project needs, i should get the datetime value sent as epoch format. I I also need that if the datetime form isn't filled-in by the user, the form will send '0' value instead of any epoch time.

Once "Submit" button clicked, i expect to send all datas issued from each selections like this way :

http://s529471052.onlinehome.fr/datetimeform/gpio/test.htm?ID=1&cmdtype=3&recurring=4&datetime=1494335700000

Would you please help me to get this working, i spend long time on without any success.

Many thanks,

Comment: basic jquery library missing.  https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You call jquery functionality before jquery .js file is loaded.
Try putting `<script>` with datetimepicker initialization after `<script>` where you load jquery.